# Install Skype4Py module on windows

Tags: python, skype4py

When i try to install the Skype4Py and run setup.py in my cmd this message comes up:

[image]

I have python 2.x. Any ideas where I am making a mistake. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just run : **python setup.py install**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an easier way to install Skype4Py would be to use Pip, which you can download from https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/ but if you are using 2.7.9+ or 3.4+ it comes preinstalled. Next you will want to run the command "pip install Skype4Py" to install the package. Once this is all installed, use the Quick-Start documentation, found here https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py#usage to help you get started. Good Luck!